# Bootstrap form input css like MS-Excel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3.0 in my project.
I want my form fields look like MS-Excel cell. What is the css for this?

This is form's current look
[image]

And code :

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2"><label>Transport Charges</label><input value="" class="form-control text-right" name="p_Frieght" id="p_Frieght"></div>
<div class="col-md-2"><label>Discount</label><input value="" class="form-control text-right" name="p_Discount" id="p_Discount"></div>
<div class="col-md-2"><label>RoundOff</label><input value="" class="form-control text-right" name="p_RoundOff" id="p_RoundOff"></div>
<div class="col-md-2"><label>Others</label><input value="" class="form-control text-right" name="p_Other" id="p_Other"></div>
<div class="col-md-3"><label>Total</label><input readonly value="" class="form-control text-right" name="p_Total" id="p_Total"></div>
</div>
```

And I want my form to look like this
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: You have to provide code

Comment: Sorry for  my incomplete question. Added my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use table tr

CSS

```
    input{border:0px solid #000; margin:0; background:transparent; width:100%}
table tr td{border-right:1px solid #000; border-bottom:1px solid #000;}
table{background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;}
    table tr:nth-child(even){background:#ccc;}
    table tr:nth-child(odd){background:#eee;}
```

HTML

```
<table cellpadding="0"; cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td width="60"><input type="text" /></td>
        <td width="60"><input type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r1frLkpo/2/

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. Can I do it without table?

Comment: Thank you. This solution better suites me.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using **BOOTSTRAP 3.0** then try to use **" Responsive tables "**, this will help you a lot and will be less time consuming for you.

Here by i am providing you a responsive table with look like Excel as you said.

Hope this helps you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap</title>
    <style type="text/css">
     input {display: block !important; padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important; width: 100% !important; border-radius: 0 !important; line-height: 1 !important;}
  td {margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```